# cant receive external mail on my ubuntu 10.10 64bit server

Tags: server, email

I've setup my server using the tutorial found here:
http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-10.10-maverick-meerkat-ispconfig-3

Everything is up and running but i can't get my external mail to work... I can send external mail but cannot receive it.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Has any of the senders received any kind of mail notification?
Have you tried to connect to your server from another network? 
Is it accessible?

Comment: yes, the server is accessible from another network. it returns this `all relevant MX records point to non-existent hosts` but my records are correct.

Comment: Perhaps you should try some nslookup queries to several DNS servers in order to check that your MX records are updated correctly.

Comment: i don't know if this helps but, previously i had centOS 5.6 installed where i had the exact opposite i could receive mail but could not send mail, and the records were exactly the same.

Comment: Find out why `point to non-existent hosts` and fix that.

Comment: how? I've tried recreating the mx record. I've used www.mxtoolbox.com and it says everything is fine. all the right ports are open. could it maybe be my isp blocking it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a firewall enabled? If yes, open the SMTP port.

The port is at:

```
$ cat /etc/services|grep smtp
smtp        25/tcp      mail
ssmtp       465/tcp     smtps       # SMTP over SSL
```

Comment: which port is the smtp port?

Comment: these are the tcp ports open in my firewall: 20,21,22,25,53,80,110,143,443,3306,8080,8081,10000

Comment: okay so i've added the 465 port to the firewall list, but still not able to receive external mail